# Structure Android LogCat Text File to Structured Pandas DF

Tags: python, android, pandas, logging, adb

I want to convert lines of LogCat Text Files to structured Pandas DF. I cannot seem to properly conceptualize how I am going to do this...Here's my basic pseudo-code:

```
dateTime = []
processID = []
threadID = []
priority = []
application = []
tag = []
text = []

logFile = "xxxxxx.log"

for line in logfile:
     split the string according to the basic structure
     dateTime = [0]
     processID = [1]
     threadID = [2]
     priority = [3]
     application = [4]
     tag = [5]
     text = [6]
     append each to the empty list above

write the lists to pandas dataframe & add column names
```

The problem is: I do not know how to properly define the delimiter with this structure

08-01 14:28:35.947   1320   1320   D wpa_xxxx: wlan1:   skip--ssid

Comment: can you specify what the seven parts of `08-01 14:28:35.947 1320 1320 D wpa_xxxx: wlan1: skip--ssid` are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

ROW_PATTERN = re.compile(r"""(\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d+) (\d+) (\d+) ([A-Z]) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)""")

with open(logFile) as f:
    s = pd.Series(f.readlines())

df = s.extract(ROW_PATTERN)
df.columns = ['dateTime', 'processID', 'threadID', 'priority', 'application', 'tag', 'text']
```

This will read each line of `logFile` into a row in a Series, which can then be expanded into a DataFrame via each group in the regular expression. This assumes that `08-01 14:28:35.947` is the first value in each row and that subsequent values are separated by white space.

Comment: So, I did not use your code verbatim but it did kick off some thoughts. Here is the code:

logs = open(r"C:\Users\rzw3ch\Documents\vehicle_logs\2021_tahoe_white_i3mh_no_comm_8_09_2021\gmlogger\gmlogger_2021_8_9_8_55_53\main.log",encoding='ISO-8859-1')

logsDf = pd.DataFrame()

for line in logs:
    logsDf = logsDf.append(pd.Series(pd.Series(line.split(' ')).values.reshape(-1)),ignore_index=True)

problem is, this approach is PAINFULLY slow. One of the files has 1.5 million lines of logs. So, now I need to find a way to chunk this or multithread the reading....any ideas?

Comment: Which is slower: `f.readlines()` or `s.extract(ROW_PATTERN)`?